# PHP upload image with ID

Tags: php

I am new to PHP programming and trying to grasp the basics, following youtube video, I was able to get a PHP form to upload basic data.
Great ! So now i just want to upload pictures..
 I have watched videos on YouTube / recoping code and trying it in so many different ways.. but still haven't been able to get it... In fact, the upload works fine but the name of the file doesn't.

i try to rename the file like img_id of "tableaux"

but i get:

**Notice: Undefined variable: taleaux in C:\xampp\htdocs\SFlamme\upload.php on line 92**

I'm sure it's something basic but i really failed to find the answer.

here is the the code I'm running on the upload form page:

```
<?php
    require_once 'Database.php';
    require_once 'function.php';



    if (!isset($_SESSION['admin']) || empty($_SESSION['admin'])) {
        header('location:index.php');
    }
    if (isset($_POST) AND !empty($_POST)) {
        if (!empty($_POST['name']) AND !empty($_POST['content']) AND !empty($_POST['size'])) {
            $req = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO tableaux(name, content, size) VALUES(:name, :content, :size)');            
            $req->bindValue(':name', $_POST['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $req->bindValue(':content', $_POST['content'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $req->bindValue(':size', $_POST['size'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $req->execute();
            $_SESSION['flash']['success'] = 'Tableau a été ajouté !';
        }else{
            $_SESSION['flash']['error'] = 'Champs manquants';
        }
    }

    if ( isset($_FILES['up_tab']) AND !empty(($_FILES['up_tab']['name'])) )
         {
             $tailleMax = 2097152; //2mo
             $extensionValides = array ('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'tif', 'png');
             if ($_FILES['up_tab']['size'] <= $tailleMax)
             {
                 $extensionUpload = strtolower(substr(strrchr($_FILES['up_tab']['name'], '.'), 1));
                 if (in_array($extensionUpload, $extensionValides))
                 {
                     $chemin = "images/tableaux/"."img_ "."." .$extensionUpload;
                     $resultat = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['up_tab']['tmp_name'],$chemin);
                     if ($resultat){
                         $updatetab = $db->prepare('UPDATE tableaux SET img_tab = :img_tab WHERE id = :id');
                         $updatetab->execute([
                         'up_tab' => "img_". "." .$extensionUpload,
                         'id' => $tableaux['id'], //HERE IS MY PROBLEME
                         ]);
                     }
                     else{
                         $msg = "erreur durant l'importation";
                     }
                 }
                 else{
                     $msg = "pas le bon format";

             }
             }
             else            {
                 $msg = "fichier supérieur à 2mo";
             }

         }
      ?>
```

Comment: You're trying to read the contents of a variable that you haven't written anything into. `$tableaux` was never created anywhere. Where is that id supposed to be coming from?

Comment: the id is suppose to come from the data base. For each picture, i have an incremetal ID, the name, short description, etc... tableaux is the name of the data base